# Endless for loop when using array.length

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, callback, infinite-loop

Randomly encountered this. When I store array.length in a variable and apply to the for loop condition using operator <= the loop works fine but when I use array.length with the same operator it becomes infinite.

```
function map(array, callback) {
  let k =array.length;
   for(let i= 1; i<=k; i++)
     {
      array[i] = callback(array[i]);
     }

    return array;
}
console.log(map([1, 2, 3], addTwo));
```

This works as expected. But when I use this

```
   function map(array, callback) {

    for(let i= 1; i<=array.length; i++)
     {

     array[i] = callback(array[i]);
     }

    return array;
    }
     console.log(map([1, 2, 3], addTwo));
```

Of course `i=0; i<array.length;` is the way to do it. But I am curious what's happening inside it.

Comment: Array has 1 element, you create a second one. Array has 2 elements, you add a third one. Array has 3 elements, you add a fourth one. Array has 4 elements, you add a fifth one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily see what happens if you add a `console.log` in there:

```js
let addTwo = x => x + 2

function map(array, callback) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= array.length; i++) {
    console.log(i, array.length)  // <-- print out i and the length of the array
    array[i] = callback(array[i]);
    if(i==5)  // <-- so we do not run out of memory
     return false
  }
  return array;
}
console.log(map([1, 2, 3], addTwo));
```

Bottom line is you are saying that the `for loop` should keep going as long as `i` is less or equal to the `array.length` but at the same time once `i` reaches the actual length of the array we continue to increase **both**. `i` via `i++` and `array.length` via `array[i] = callback(array[i]);` so there is no end in sight.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case the variable with the length does not change, but in the second, you take the length directly and this change.

```
let k = array.length;
```

keeps a length until the iterator reaches an index greater than `k`.

The other one

```
for (let i = 1; i <= array.length; i++)
//                 ^
```

takes the actual length and while the index is compared against the length adds one index to the array for every call at the end of the original array.